# Python live output from subprocess that doesn't flush its own buffer

Tags: python

I want to write a Python(3.7) script that runs a C++ executable and live prints the output. However, I run into issues when the executable does not flush its own buffer. The following C++ executable (compiled simply with `g++ -o main main.cpp`) and Python script works as expected due to `std::endl` flushing the stream buffer:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    for(auto i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

```py
# run_main.py
import subprocess

def main():
    process = subprocess.Popen(["./main"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8")

    while True:
        realtime_output = process.stdout.readline()
        if realtime_output == "" and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if realtime_output != "":
            print(f"Python:: {realtime_output.strip()}", flush=True)

    process.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, if I change the `std::endl` to a newline character (`"\n"`) in the C++ file,

```cpp
std::cout << "i = " << i << "\n";
```

then the Python program will wait until the executable has terminated to print anything. How can I get each output line-by-line based on the newline? I want to do further processing (filtering) with each line that comes into the Python script.

I have tried adding the `-u` flag when running `./main` from the subprocess, but to no avail. I have also tried flushing `stdout` in my Python script both with `print(..., flush=True)` and `process.stdout.flush()`.

EDIT:
I know I can use `process.stdout.read()` and do some manual buffering on the `\n`, but is there any built-in methodology to do so?

Comment: Use `pexpect`. It will run the child process using a pty, which will usually cause the program to use line buffering instead of full buffering.

Comment: I'd like to avoid external modules if possible

Comment: Then you'll have to write your own code that uses a pty. There's nothing you can do in `subprocess()` to prevent the C++ application from buffering if it's writing to a pipe.

Comment: Before starting down the road of writing a pty controller, does the application in question even care if it's connected to a terminal? For example, does `unbuffer` affect how it flushes output? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe